# wordpress stylesheet loaded for specific page loads on all pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to enqueue a stylesheet on a specific page, what actually happens is it automatically gets loaded into all of the pages.

I've tried it within functions.php with `is_page('page-slug')` and `is_page_template('template-name.php');`

I've tried loading it in the header as well, with the same if statements and it still loads on every page..

The weird thing is that when I `echo 'test';` from within the statements, the echo actually gets displayed on the specified page / page template and not the other pages.

I've tried using `wp_dequeue_style('style-name');` but i'm not sure that I'm using it correctly.

Why is my stylesheet still being loaded on every page?

**Edit:**
The following if statement is currently in my header.php

```
if ( is_page( 'page-slug' ) ) {
  echo "test";
  wp_enqueue_style( 'foo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/stylesheets/foo.css' );
} else {
  wp_dequeue_style('foo');
}
```

Regards,

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code i.e. your `if`-block.

Comment: give us the complete code and also the page where you wanna put the stylesheet

Comment: Please include the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Have you tried clearing your cache? How do you know the style sheet is being loaded? Are you just judging that by what you see, or do the dev tools show this?

Comment: Hi,
I've edited the post to include the if else statement.

My apolagies for not doing that in the first place.

@j08691 I've cleared the browser cache multiple times, I have not cleared the server cache (waiting for access to that) I know the stylesheet is being loaded on all pages because in that stylesheet i've added:
`body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}`
and none of the pages are scrollable anymore.

Comment: When I looked at the element inspector, I noticed the stylesheets were being loaded with a specific version on all pages, I changed the version of the stylesheet but It was still loading the newer version on all pages.